# How do I do flickerless image switch on hover with CSS only?

Tags: css

The code is as follows:

```
<div id="compv-navbar">
        <a href="#"><img src="image1.png" id="icon1"></a> | 
        <a href="#"><img src="image2.png" id="icon2"></a> | 
        <a href="#"><img src="image3.png" id="icon3"></a> | 
        <span id="view_name"> Random Text</span>
 </div>
```

Assume that each image has another image with suffix '-hover' that will be image to be replaced on hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what i would do:

```
<div id="compv-navbar">
        <a href="#" id="icon1"></a> | 
        <a href="#" id="icon2"></a> | 
        <a href="#" id="icon3"></a> | 
        <span id="view_name"> Random Text</span>
</div>

a#icon1{
background:url("image1.png") no-repeat;
}
a:hover#icon1{
background:url("image1-hover.png") no-repeat;
}
a#icon2{
background:url("image2.png") no-repeat;
}
a:hover#icon2{
background:url("image2-hover.png") no-repeat;
}
a#icon3{
background:url("image3.png") no-repeat;
}
a:hover#icon3{
background:url("image3-hover.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it should work...but based on my situation...it doesn't work. It messes with the alignment.

I will have to use jQuery to do it. 

Thnx though.

Answer (score 1):

CSS isn't meant to do this, it controls presentation, not the
location of files. If you really need this however, here's a little work-around they should work (I haven't actually tested this yet).

HTML

```
<div id="compv-navbar"> 
        <a href="#"><span id="icon1"></span></a> |  
        <a href="#"><span id="icon2"></span></a> |  
        <a href="#"><span id="icon3"></span></a> |  
        <span id="view_name"> Random Text</span> 
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#icon1
{
    width:100px; /*Change this to your image width*/
    height:100px; /*Change this to your image width*/
    background-image:url("image1.png");
}

#icon1:hover
{
    width:100px; /*Change this to your image width*/
    height:100px; /*Change this to your image width*/
    background-image:url("image1-hover.png");
}
```

(Make sure you add this for each image.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, totally flickerless image switch you can do only with image preloading. In any other case browser will load image only **on** hover. I wrote [a small example](http://jsfiddle.net/VSkWZ/5/) about image switching.

Another solution is to use [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-only-image-preloading/) and switch image on hover using `background-position`.